# Unable to fetch nested object in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

profile/view.js

```js
const ViewProfile = () => {
    const router = useRouter();

    //Working as expected
    const user = useUserData();
    console.log(user);

    //unable to fetch this
    const data = user.profile;
    console.log(data);

    //Rest of the code
}
```

This is my ViewProfile component. Whenever I fetch user data through useUserData hook, I can log the user object without any issue. But as soon as I try to access the user.profile object, I get an error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'profile')`.

useUserData.js

```js
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useUserData = () => {
    const userToken = Cookies.get("sessionToken");
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URI}/user/profile`,{
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Authorization": `Bearer ${userToken}`,
                    },
                });

                const data = await res.json();
                if (res.ok) {
                    setUserData(data);
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        }
    
        if (userToken) {
            fetchData();
        }

    }, [userToken]);

    return userData;
};

export default useUserData;
```

When I log the user object, the profile object is also present. The problem arises as soon as I log the profile object.
I have checked the API and it is working fine. I think there is some issue with my `useEffect` implementation.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please reformat your code, so it's easier to read for people who try to help you. What I can say at first look: Avoid defining functions in the `useEffect()` call. Does the function really has to be redefined every time, `useEffect` is executed?

Comment: @kzi I have defined the function in the `useEffect()` because I got some errors while fetching the data using async-await. After some research, I found this is a way to make it work. If you know the correct or conventional approach, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the reformatting! You could just execute the function inside your `useEffect()` call without defining it there. Maybe you would have to give a parameter to the function. But that's just a way, you could improve the performance, because the time, needed to redefine the function every time, `useEffect` runs, is saved. Looks like your problem was solved anyway, glad to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get to know how React renders your component, basically it re-renders each time component's state changed. Here is the flow from your component + hook:

- First of all, your component renders with state `userData = null` which is the init value for the state which means `const user = useUserData();` the `user` object is `null` in this case and where you encountered the issue
- Once the endpoint returns the value for you and you already set the new state `userData`, the `user` object is becoming an object that you need which is a defined object

As a result of that, you need to handle the case that `user` can be null such as:

```
if (!user) {
   // show loading state
   return <Loading />
}

// now display the user information
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
const user = await useUserData()
```

or

```
const data = await user.profile
```

Also log the user and see what you get.

```
console.log(user)
```